# Identify the Phone Field in UCI of Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, phone-call, dynamics-crm-uci

On Contact form we have two phone fields (Mobile and Business). In UCI, beside phone fields there is Phone icon that opens Phone Call Activity form (Quick Create or Main Form) once we tap on it.

Now the issue is, the Phone Number field of Phone Call Activity form don't capture the phone number either it is opened by tap from Business Phone or Mobile Phone.

Anyone have idea to identify by which field (Business or Mobile) the phone call activity form is opened?

Comment: If the answer was helpful, upvote/thank/accept it to help community finding it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation, when the OOB click-to-dial icon is clicked - the call should go out based on Skype or any other telephony system integration you may have and configured, then the phonecall (call log) activity should be captured with notes, etc to cover the use case.

But as we may have multiple phone number fields in any entity form and the crm user can click any one of them to reach the end user, this gets tricky. Also the icon cannot be customized or hooked with some custom event handlers to achieve what we want. [Same issue was discussed here](https://www.crmug.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?GroupId=1285&MessageKey=631ef36e-fdd3-4c32-bb84-3a7bfdae1b61&CommunityKey=dc83c23b-ede0-4070-ae7a-dd90859148a6&tab=digestviewer#bm631ef36e-fdd3-4c32-bb84-3a7bfdae1b61)

Worst case, we can map one fixed field between contact and phone call or some javascript to pull always the same Business phone field, but this don't serve the purpose.

Interestingly, I have implemented some telephony integration with the help of some third party providers who uses the Channel integration framework (CIF), which provides them a custom PCF button - this button implementation can be customized and the necessary fields can be mapped and filled out.

But OOB click-to-dial is so limited. Nothing can be done to fulfill this semi-cooked functionality.

Comment: Thank you Arun, can you please share that custom PCF button control.

Comment: @MohsinA. You can install CIF and try it. Or develop your own PCF control.

Comment: Hello Guys, 
I have more-or-less same problem, I needed to initiate the call from my custom telephony and we have UCI interface, however we are using on premise MS CRM version and that does not have CIF.  We are not able to initiate an outbound call from our custom Telephony , Is there any solution for this ?